# Trouble reading HTML in Adobe Illustrator ExtendScript extension

Tags: extendscript

I am working on an Adobe Illustrator ExtendScript extension, and I'm facing an issue with reading HTML files. I have created a manifest file, and Illustrator seems to recognize it correctly, but when I try to load an HTML file, it doesn't work as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Illustrator Extension</title>
    <!-- Link to your CSS files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/topcoat-desktop-dark.css">

    <!-- Include your JavaScript files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CSInterface.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <!-- Header section with logo -->
        <div id="logo">
            <img id="logoimage" src="assets/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width: 480px; height: 120px;">
        </div>

        <!-- Main content area -->
        <div>
            <div id="palettes" style="width: 490px; height: 400px;">
                <!-- Your dynamic content goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Buttons and tooltips -->
        <div>
            <div class="buttons" style="width: 490px; height: 45px;">
                <button id="addButton" class="topcoat-button--large">+</button>
                <span id="helptip">This will include tips for the users</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z85Nb.png)